# Re-implementation of OrderBy, ThenBy and Null TypeMapping in Sql Tree error

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I am trying to implement `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` in a different way to hide lambda expression from `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` extension methods. These extension methods accept classes which implement `IOrderSpecification`:

```
public class PersonOrderByAgeSpecification : OrderSpecification<Person>
{
    public PersonOrderByAgeSpecification(Sort direction= Sort.Ascending) : base(direction)
    {
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Person, IComparable>> AsExpression()
    {
        return personOrder => personOrder.Age;
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
 var orderSpecification = new PersonOrderByAgeSpecification(Sort.Ascending); 
 var sortedPeople=  _dbContext.People.OrderBy(orderSpecification);
```

It works fine when the property type in `AsExpression()` is just string. For example:

```
public override Expression<Func<Person, IComparable>> AsExpression()
{
    return personOrder => personOrder.FirstName;
}
```

Otherwise I would get this error: (Does not work with integer or bool)

> InvalidOperationException: Null TypeMapping in Sql Tree
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Query.Pipeline.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor+SqlTypeMappingVerifyingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression
>   node)

The source code is available [here](https://github.com/peymanknowit/OrderSpecification)

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably tested this before but I -just in case- tested it using a `List<Person>` I made up, against `string`, `int` and `bool` sortings all of which worked just fine.
It seems like you are hitting an issue with EFCore's RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor, which can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/a2167dcaee79cd49fbb54893efe67da4878d1830/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Pipeline/RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.cs You might want to open a new issue.

Comment: I think so too. Right now I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version 3.0.0-preview3.19153.1. I didn't experience the same thing with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.X.X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are using preview (beta) software, which is expected to have issues.

But the main problem is that LINQ ordering methods have second generic type argument `TKey`, which you are hiding behind `IComparable`, which for value types causes a hidden cast inside the expression.

Apart from unnecessary boxing, this is not a problem for LINQ to Objects provider because it simply compiles and executes a delegate from the lambda expression. However other `IQueryable` providers usually need to translate the expression to something else (usually SQL). Most of them identify such casts (`Expression.Convert`) and remove them during the processing. Apparently EF 3.0 preview you are using doesn't, hence the exception.

You can avoid such issues by eliminating the hidden casts yourself. It's possible to do that with expression manipulation, but the easiest is to introduce the second generic type argument to your base abstract class:

```
public abstract class OrderSpecification<T, TKey> : IOrderSpecification<T>
```

and change the abstract method signature to

```
public abstract Expression<Func<T, TKey>> AsExpression();
```

The implementation, interface and everything else except the concrete classes will remain as is.

Now all you need is to specify the actual key type in the inherited class and change the `AsExpression` override signature. For instance:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class PersonAgeOrderSpecification : OrderSpecification<Person, int>
{
    public PersonAgeOrderSpecification(Sort direction) : base(direction) { }
    public override Expression<Func<Person, int>> AsExpression()
    {
        return person => person.Age;
    }
}
```

and everything will be fine.